# COM object created by CComObject::CreateInstance not destroyed when pointer goes out of scope

Tags: c++, com, visual-studio-2013, atl

Using smart pointer `CComObject` I create a COM object by calling its static method `CreateInstance`. But when I leave my program, at least in VS13, that object remains running. Here is my code:

```
CComObject< CMyAtlObject > * myAtlCOMObject = NULL;
HRESULT hr = CComObject< CMyAtlObject >::CreateInstance(&myAtlCOMObject);
ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
```

I expected the `~CComObject()` method to be called when going out of scope which does not happen.

I tried putting the code above in curly braces to force the newly created object to go out scope.
I tried calling `FinalRelease` on `myAtlCOMObject` and succeeded in manually calling `Release` on `myAtlCOMObject`, but the program still didn't stop running in VS13.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the code with inline comments:

```
{
  CComObject<CMyAtlObject>* myAtlCOMObject = NULL;
  HRESULT hr = CComObject< CMyAtlObject >::CreateInstance(&myAtlCOMObject);
  ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
  // NOTE: Created new object with reference count of ZERO
  {
    const CComQIPtr<IMyAtlObject> pMyAtlObject = myAtlCOMObject;
    // NOTE: Reference count increased to ONE
  }
  // NOTE: ~CComQIPtr went out of scope and called IUnknown::Release 
  //       decrementing counter to ZERO; decrement to zero causes destruction
}
// NOTE: There is no ~CComObject call here on myAtlCOMObject going out of scope
//       since myAtlCOMObject is a raw pointer
```

> What am I missing?

You are missing the following:

- `CreateInstance` creates a new object and gets you raw pointer which is not going to self-destroy on leaving scope
- `CreateInstance` creates an object in "unstable" state with refcount of zero, it's self-desrtuction on reference management starts after something increments refcount AT LEAST ONCE and then decrements it to zero; `CComQIPtr` above is an example of this

[MSDN on `CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e31say1.aspx):

> The object returned has a reference count of zero, so call AddRef immediately, then use Release to free the reference on the object pointer when you're done.

#### What do you use instead of `CComObject::CreateInstance`?

I have a [helper template class `CObjectPtr`](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Common/alax.info/roatlcom.h#L121) which acts in the way similar to well known `CComPtr` and wraps/manages native C++ class.

My code would be:

```
CObjectPtr<CFoo> pFoo;
pFoo.Construct(); // Instantiates automatically adding reference
CFoo* pRawFoo = pFoo; // Acts as a pointer
CComPtr<IFoo> pFooInterface = pFoo; // Good for exposing inmepleted interafaces
CObjectPtr<CFoo> pAnotherFoo = pFoo; // Same instance proper reference counting
// ~CObjectPtr releases reference, destroys the object on last release
```

Another simple wrapper is also provided in this answer: [How to better initialize a reference counter for a non-creatable COM object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070111/how-to-better-initialize-a-reference-counter-for-a-non-creatable-com-object/2070164#2070164).

Comment: Got it. I can now exit my MFC program and the memory leak dumps work again because the COM objects have been properly released.

Comment: No! If you use `CComQIPtr` with an interface type which is for whatever reason unsupported by the object you get the object leaked. It should be `CComPtr` here instead.

Comment: This is correct, my code snippet was somewhat simplifying things. Both `CComPtr`, `CComQIPtr` do fine if interface is implemented/available. Otherwise `CComPtr` would rather cause compiler error, and `CComQIPtr` would rather fail on runtime instead. I personally never use `CComObject::CreateInstance` directly on real code.

Comment: What do you use instead of CComObject::CreateInstance? CoCreateInstance?

Comment: @rtischer8277 presumably `CoCreateInstance` would end up in this code. You are instantiating a C++ class which implements a COM object so I am assuming this code appears in a class factory that you are writing yourself.